# 404 media urls in Fire Bug

Tags: magento-1.9, htaccess

I am getting lots of 404 errors in Fire Bug's Net tab. I have attached the screen shot to know more. The error gets continuously incremented in Fire Bug. I have checked for this and getting solutions for this but not related to this type of problem.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the Magento media folder permissions issue!

Check the permission of media folder & files in it.
Try to give 777 or, 770 permission and check.

following commands can be used to set permissions from ssh:

- find media/ -type f -exec chmod 777 {} \;
- find media/ -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

Comment: Thanks Rahul. But that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the js/css file paths in the source and open it manually to confirm the paths are correct. if paths are correct then please make sure that cache is disabled for development. ALso in cache management clear cache for js and css.